# Start Mongodb as service requires persmissions on data dirs

Tags: linux, mongodb

I'm new to linux and mongodb so this is probably a newbe question...

I can start mongo like this (alt #1)

```
$ mongod --dbpath /mnt/datadrive/data --logpath /mnt/datadrive/data/mongod.log
```

But when I start is "service-wise" (alt #2)

```
$ sudo service mongod start
```

I get:

```
Starting mongod: can't open /mnt/datadrive/data/mongod.log
for log file: errno:13 Permission denied
```

(i've set the dbpath and logpath in /etc/mongod.conf)

So, is mongod started with a different user when run alt #2? What account is that?

If so, how do I allow that account to access /mnt/datadrive/data/ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chown -R mangodb /mnt/datadrive
```

Comment: Voilà! Is there some bad security aspects of doing this?

Comment: No, Its always best practice to run services with non-privilege users.

Comment: @Cotten the security aspect depends on what is in that folder, if it is stuff that only mongodb is supposed to touch then there isn't much of a security problem however if there is other stuff in there then it could be a security issue

Comment: @Sammaye Thank you! Sounds reasonable. Kind of the answer I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a RHEL distro then in the `/etc/init.d/mongod` script you probably have:

```
daemon --user mongodb "$exec --quiet $options run >> $logfile 2>&1 &"
```

Check the permissions on `/mnt/datadrive/`, it is very likely that the `mongodb` user cannot access this location.

Comment: How do I find the mongod user account? I've looked through the file cat /etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod | grep user
  daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" $NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS and echo $MONGO_USER is empty...

Comment: I'm use the EPEL RPM (`mongodb-server 2.2.3-4.el6`), which sets up the user as `mongodb`. Are you building and using the [RPM from GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/init.d-mongod)? If so, it has a different init script and their default user is called `mongod`.